# Clone an Ecto record. With embeds and associated records?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

What is the easiest way to clone an Ecto model / record? I have a sample recipe model with many ingredients and embedded labels.

Model

```
defmodule App.Recipe do
use App.Web, :model

schema "recipes" do
  field :name, :string
  has_many :ingredients, App.Ingredient
  embeds_many :labels, App.Label
end
```

**Clone recipe record**
How can I clone a recipe record and create a changeset for inserting a new recipe record?

```
recipe = Repo.get(App.Recipe, 1)
recipe_changeset = Ecto.Changeset.change(recipe)

# ... Steps for cloning record with embeds?  

new_recipe = Repo.insert(recipe_changeset)
```

**Clone recipe and ingredients and assign new recipe id to ingredients**

How can I clone a recipe record with preloaded ingrediens for inserting a new recipe record with new ingredients?

```
recipe = Repo.get(App.Recipe, 1)
        |> Repo.preload(:ingredients)
recipe_changeset = Ecto.Changeset.change(recipe)

# ... Steps for cloning records?              

new_recipe = Repo.insert(recipe_changeset)
```

Comment: You want to also clone all the ingredients and set their `recipe_id` to the new recipe's id, right?

Comment: Yes, i want to clone all ingredients and assign the new recipe id to them.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the id before you insert it again.

```
Repo.get(App.Recipe, 1)
|> Repo.preload(:ingredients)
|> whatever_you_wanna_do
|> Map.delete(:id)
|> Repo.insert
```